# Impementing menu for flutter web in mobile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hello I recently started a project on flutter web and am having problems implementing Menu for Mobile view in the NavBar.
[Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxfmj.png).
This is what i need when i click the menu icon. 
[Onclick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAivp.png)

Comment: This is a forum dealing with specific programming problems, you have to show what you have done so far and where did you stack. Hav a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific kind of widget you are looking for is called a drawer. You may visit 
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/drawer for full details. Let me also give an example of a drawer code.

```
class Trial extends State<State1> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Choose an Option:',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              child: Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    size: 35,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    'Increment by 2',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      increment = 2;
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

Please note. This is not the specific code that was asked for. I have only provided a neat example that may be tweaked to arrive at the necessary result.